# Mulitiple row insert in Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is it possible to insert multiple rows in Sequel, and how it would be done?
Can anyone explain it to me?

I've tried something like this:

```
DB[:table].insert([:x, :y], [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Dataset#multi_insert](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-multi_insert).

Although the document describes that it issues two `INSERT`s, it seems to issue only one `INSERT` with multiple values, at least for PostgreSQL.

```
>> DB[:table].multi_insert([{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}])
INSERT INTO "table" ("x", "y") VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use array of value arrays(`[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`) for inserting, instead of array of column,value hashes(`[{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}]`), you can use [Dataset#import](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel%2FDataset:import).

```
> DB[:test].import([:x, :y], [[1, 2], [3, 4]])
# => ["INSERT INTO `test` (`x`, `y`) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4)"]
```